# VBA adding worksheets from list

Tags: vba, excel

I am still very new at VBA and I am having trouble getting some code to work. I have one sub where I want to create worksheets based off of a list of names in a worksheet named AllCities. The list of city names starts in cell A2. The worksheets need to be named after the cell value in the list, and the list should be able to be updated.  The code right now works kind of, but it doesn't add new worksheets if I add to the list of names. My second sub is supposed to delete an any worksheets that do not correspond to a city on the list. My delete sub is just deleting every worksheet right now.

**Insert Worksheet Code:**

```
Sub insertSheets()

Dim myCell As Range
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyRange2 As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("AllCities").Range("A2")
Set MyRange2 = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each myCell In MyRange2
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = myCell.Value

Next myCell

End Sub
```

**Delete Worksheet Code:**

```
Sub deleteSheets()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range

Set wks = Sheets("AllCities")

With wks
    Set MyRange = Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each myCell In MyRange
    Sheets(myCell.Value).Delete
Next myCell
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help that you have!

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use two different methods (that will yield different results) to find the last cell in the range.

In your `insertSheets` procedure, you're using:

```
Set MyRange2 = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
```

This is the same effect as holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing the down key which will find the last cell before a blank cell is present.

In your `deleteSheets` procedure you use:

```
Set MyRange = Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

This has a different effect from the way you searched in the `insertSheets` procedure as it starts from the bottom of the worksheet to find the true last cell in the range.

I suggest amending your `insertSheets` procedure to:

```
Sub insertSheets()

Dim myCell As Range
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyRange2 As Range

With Sheets("AllCities")
    Set MyRange = .Range("A2")
    Set MyRange2 = .Range(MyRange, .Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
End With

For Each myCell In MyRange2
    If Not myCell.Value = vbNullString Then
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = myCell.Value
    End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

This will also validate that the cell is not blank and therefore prevent Excel from throwing an error because you trying to rename a new worksheet to having no name.

Comment: I am still getting an error when I run the insert sub after adding another city to the list. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: What is the error and on what line is it occurring on?